# Powershell ExecutionPolicy is wrong when run through VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script as part of my Pre-Build on a VS2005 project. I have run

```
$> powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted
```

from a command line before the build and I can run the same script from from the command line. However when the script is run as part of the Pre-Build step it fails with

```
The execution of scripts is disabled on this system. 
Please see “get-help about_signing” for more details.
```

The script works on a co-worker's x32 XP machine, but not on my x64 Windows7 machine.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Did you set the execution policy in both the 64 and 32 bit Powershell environments?  Your 64 bit machine will have both, and each has it's own executionpolicy setting.

Comment: 64-bit will run by default on a 64-bit machine. To set it for 32-bit, you need to run C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe (Source: http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/20443-powershell-32bit-or-64bit-and-execution-policy)