# Visual studio2015- Cannot create a new project

Tags: visual-studio

There are some powershell experts in my place and they go about disabling almost everything.

I created a new Visual studio project, say a web forms one. The project doesn't get created and it gives me a message "Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. See the image below:

[image]

A bit of debugging the can infer the machine policy is set to "remoteSigned". Though I set the rights to "unrestricted" it cannot be overridden.

[image]

I don't have super admin rights on the machine.

Any ideas on how I can overcome this problem.

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to need an elevated (read admin) powershell session to change the machine policy.  Also you're setting yourself up for a bad time trying to run VS without admin.  If you absolutly can't get admin rights on the box, you'd probably be better off running VS inside a VM.

Comment: I am already part of the Administrator group in the machine. Do I need elevated permissions?

Comment: I am already part of the administrative group. Do I need more permissions. Why is the machinepolicy set as RemoteSigned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142914/powershell-executionpolicy-is-wrong-when-run-through-visualstudio#6143090 might help.  Possibly this as well https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/974